# If I reset all my skills, do I lose the bonuses from critical success in missions?

Tags: star-trek-online

Basically... I never really understood skills/I thought if I played long enough, I could max them all out.

I am annoyed at how I spent quite a few of my skill points and I have also had critical success in quite a few duty officer missions that have awarded skill points, some of which have are in skills I already maxed out - so are pretty useless.

I was just wondering, if I get a respec/reskill/reset token and use it, do all of the skills that I have won stats in also reset to 0, or do I keep critical success skill buffs?

(Side question - if I loose them (or even if I don't), is there a complete list of every possible win from missions so that I know not to spend skill points in them, as give enough time, I should fill them from missions?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like I got this wrong - I assumed it was a permanent skill point, but, it looks like you only get temporary buffs from critical missions - so, my problem isn't really an issue at all.

I will respec and just be more careful where I spend points.